# EMGU OpenCV disparity only on certain pixels

Tags: opencv, emgucv, disparity-mapping

I'm using the EMGU OpenCV wrapper for c#.  I've got a disparity map being created nicely.  However for my specific application I only need the disparity values of very few pixels, and I need them in real time.  The calculation is taking about 100 ms now, I imagine that by getting disparity for hundreds of pixel values rather than thousands things would speed up considerably.  I don't know much about what's going on "under the hood" of the stereo solver code, is there a way to speed things up by only calculating the disparity for the pixels that I need?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you fail to mention what you are really trying to accomplish, and moreover, what algorithm you are using. E.g. StereoGC is a really slow (i.e. not real-time), but usually far more accurate) compared to both StereoSGBM and StereoBM. Those last two can be used real-time, providing a few conditions are met:

- The size of the input images is reasonably small;
- You are not using an extravagant set of parameters (for instance, a larger value for `numberOfDisparities` will increase computation time).

Don't expect miracles when it comes to accuracy though.

Apart from that, there is the issue of "just a few pixels". As far as I understand, the algorithms implemented in OpenCV usually rely on information from more than 1 pixel to determine the disparity value. E.g. it needs a neighborhood to detect which pixel from image A map to which pixel in image B. As a result, in general it is not possible to just discard every other pixel of the image (by the way, if you already know the locations in both images, you would not need the stereo methods at all). So unless you can discard a large border of your input images for which you know that you'll never find your pixels of interest there, I'd say the answer to this part of your question would be "no".

If you happen to know that your pixels of interest will always be within a certain rectangle of the input images, you can specify the input image ROIs (regions of interest) to this rectangle. Assuming OpenCV does not contain a bug here this should speedup the computation a little.

With a bit of googling you can to find real-time examples of finding stereo correspondences using EmguCV (or plain OpenCV) using the GPU on Youtube. Maybe this could help you.

*Disclaimer: this may have been a more complete answer if your question contained more detail.*